# What strategies can I use to dynamically choose which column to filter on?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pass into a T-SQL stored procedure two integer values, which will be used to determine which columns I'll use in the WHERE clause. The table involved as 4 columns in it named Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4.

If I pass in 1 for the first integer and 3 for the second integer, I want the WHERE to use Q1 and Q3. I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: you'll probably be able to use or clauses, or some case when, but you should show the relevant part of your code if you want an answer.

Comment: What would the WHERE clause look like? Do you want to compare Q1 and Q3 for equality. You would seem to have 12 possible combinations. But if you want to test equality, you could reduce this to 6 by ordering the 2 parameter values.

Comment: It might be simpler and more effective to use 2 stored procs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send in your indices as a list and then do this as dynamic SQL string.

```
select <columnlist>
from <table>
where (1 in @indices and column1 = @value)
  OR (2 in @indices and column2 = @value)
  OR (3 in @indices and column3 = @value)
  OR (4 in @indices and column4 = @value)
```

Or something using that pattern, which matches your (incompletely specified) logic.

Or use the two parameters and make your where conditions like this, if you're sure there will only ever be two parameters...

```
select <columnlist>
from <table>
where ((1 = @index1 OR 1 = @index2) and column1 = @value)
  OR ((2 = @index1 OR 2 = @index2) and column2 = @value)
  OR ((3 = @index1 OR 3 = @index2) and column3 = @value)
  OR ((4 = @index1 OR 4 = @index2) and column4 = @value)
```